# Find 1 point from 3 Angles, 2 Points and 1 unit vector

Tags: geometry, triangles

i have the following problem:

[image: problem]

Given are points **P1** and **P2**. I also have the direction, in the image noted as **D**, given as a unit vector.
Additionally, I have the angles **alpha** and **gamma** and I know that **beta** is 90°.

Now I Want to find point **P3** which lies on the direction vector D.
The direction vector and the line from P3 to P2 form a 90° angle.

Do you have ideas how to solve this? Probably the problem is quite simple. Unfortunately I'm not very good at math, so excuse my question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does "finding a point" mean?

Comment: by finding a point I mean, I want to calculate the coordinates of that point

Comment: Does it mean, that the coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$ are given? How is the unit vector given? Is $\alpha $ the angle between the directions $D$ and $P_1P_2 $?

Comment: yes, P1 and P2 are given. α is the angle between the directions D and P1P2. I calculated the unit vector from two points that are parallel to the direction passing through P1. Does that make sense?

Comment: It would be much simpler if you list directly in question all given parameters. I still cannot get the parameters defining the direction but by any choice of them, the angle $\alpha $ will be fixed and cannot be treated as a free parameter.

Comment: I thought my numbers are not looking to well. But I hope this helps explain my question. P1 = (1.0404, 0.6314, 0.2441),  P2 = (0.9880, 0.7511, 0.3283), D = (-0.6626, 0.4542, 0.5956), α = 26.4, β = 90,  γ = 63.6. Sorry, if this is still murky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the vector form the answer reads:
$${\mathbf P}_3= {\mathbf P}_1+(({\mathbf P}_2-{\mathbf P}_1)\cdot{\mathbf D}){\mathbf D}. $$

As clarified in comments the angle $\alpha $ is not a free parameter and is "hiďden" in the dot product.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Hope this helps.